# nftables config for ipsec (strongswan) vpn

Tags: networking, ipsec, strongswan, nftables

If have got a working IPSec connection between a device (raspberry) on remote side (`10.X.117.0/24` network) and the local network (`10.Y.0.0/16` network).

The raspberry has a static `10.X.117.1` IP on its `eth0` LAN interface and `192.168.8.120` on its `eth1` interface via DHCP via a LTE token which is used for the IPSec connection.

From the local network I can access the raspberry via `10.X.117.1`.

But in addition I want to access:

1. all devices (with static IPs) in the remote `10.X.117.0/24` network which are connected to `eth0` from the local network such as via `10.X.117.60`.

2. the local network from the devices in the remote network.

Firewall settings on local network (PFsense) are fine because with Edge-router devices both accesses are working.

On the raspberry I have got `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
and `/etc/nftables.conf`:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f


flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter;
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter;
        }
}
```

(Allow everything for the beginning / default config.)
On `10.X.117.60` there are the same settings in `nftables.conf`.

`nmap` reports `filtered` for all the accesses accporing to 1. and 2.

What else do I need to set?